# Create a link_to to an object identified with a slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails 4.2 application, vanity URLs are used for some models and are invoked in the controller as:

```
@staticpage = Staticpage.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
```

However, various attempts at creating a link_to fail.  Example:

```
<%= link_to 'this', staticpage_url(33, locale: I18n.locale.to_s) %>
```

as this generates a link which looks for the id, in lieu of the slug.

How can the slug be invoked in a link_to statement while ensuring that locale is respected? *the slug is not localized*

Comment: are you using the freindly_id gem?

Comment: I believe you refer to friendly_id  (spelling) gem.  No, this is not being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be best using the [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem:

```
#app/models/staticpage.rb
class Staticpage < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :param, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end
```

This automatically inserts the `slug` into the `link_to` and `path helper` methods, overriding `.find` to use the `slug`...

```
<% Staticpage.all.each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to "x", page %>
<% end %>

def show
  @page = Staticpage.find params[:id] #-> finds by slug
end
```